# Replace comma with blank in vba

Tags: vba

I have to replace comma in the last column of any row with blank.I have below in excel.

```
 1      _1 "",
 2      _2 "",
 3      _3 "",
 4      _4 "",
 5      _5 "",
```

My code. but it is not working.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim lRow As Long
  Dim length As Long

  'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
  lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  length = Len(Range("C" & lRow)) - 1
  Range("C" & lRow).Value = Replace(Range("C" & lRow), ",", "", length)
  Range("B2:B" & lRow).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: You mean the last row in a given cell (as the code indicates) - not the last column in any row. right?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick: It will remove the last character in the last row if it is a comma (this assumes that you want to replace in column C as your code indicates):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim lRow As Long

  lRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  If Right(Range("C" & lRow).Value, 1) = "," Then
    Range("C" & lRow).Value = Left(Range("C" & lRow), Len(Range("C" & lRow)) - 1)
  End If

  Range("B2:B" & lRow).ClearContents
End Sub
```

You could also use the replace, but it is trickier that way.